# Marked ( Markdown ) + Mermaid ( Flow Chart & Diagrams )

Tags: javascript, markdown, flowchart, mermaid, javascript-marked

Struggling to get 
Mermaid - https://github.com/knsv/mermaid
to work with
Marked - https://github.com/chjj/marked

From what I gather I should be able to write the following in markdown

````
```
  graph TD;A-->B;A-->C;B-->D;C-->D;
```
````

and have it render

```
<div class="mermaid">
   FLOWCHART / DIAGRAM IS DRAWN HERE
</div>
```

What am I missing?

````
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Document</title>
      <script src="libs/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="libs/marked.min.js"></script>
      <script src="libs/mermaid.full.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="content"></div>

    <script>

      var renderer = new marked.Renderer();
      renderer.code = function (code, language) {
        if(code.match(/^sequenceDiagram/)||code.match(/^graph/)){
           return '<div class="mermaid">'+code+'</div>';
        }
      };

        $(document).ready(function(){

        $.get( "test.md", function( data ) {
          // console.log(data);
          $('#content').html(marked(data));
        });

      });

    console.log(marked('```graph TD;A-->B;A-->C;B-->D;C-->D;```', { renderer: renderer }));

    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
````

Answer (score 2):

I tested your code as far as to get the console.log writing the mermaid div.

There is nothing wrong with your marked instantiation and nothing wrong with your renderer. However... the markdown in the console log was not ok.

By adding new lines before and after the graph definition the expeced div was printed to the console.:

\ngraph TD;A-->B;A-->C;B-->D;C-->D;\n

I hope this helps.

/Knut

Answer (score 0):

I had that issue as well.
Try this string format, it worked for me:

> 'graph TB\n'+'A --> B\n'+'A --> C\n'+'B --> D\n'+'C --> D\n'

Answer (score 0):

For me, [Mermaid](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid) diagrams render fine in [Marked 2](https://marked2app.com/) (version: 2.6.4).

Example markdown source:

````
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mermaid@8.8.4/dist/mermaid.min.js"></script>
```mermaid
graph TD;A-->B;A-->C;B-->D;C-->D;

```
````

Caveat: it seems Mermaid needs to be invoked twice after each edit. So after an edit, once Marked 2 has updated its streaming preview, I need to hit "Refresh".

Marked 2 settings:

- "Generating typographically correct quotes and punctuation" unchecked
- Syntax highlighting: unchecked
- Processor: either MultiMarkdown or Discount

Related posts on the Marked 2 forum:

- [Using mermaid in Marked 2](http://support.markedapp.com/discussions/problems/156732-using-mermaid-in-marked-2)
- [Mermaid Diagrams in Documents](http://support.markedapp.com/discussions/questions/8184-mermaid-diagrams-in-documents)